# Viewport of render gone, I joined Areas to area with folders

Tags: 3d-view

My mistake was joined the area of folders to right side, when I wanted take of them.
[image: Mistake]

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

**Go to**
[image: Click in plus button]

**later:**
[image]

**done!**
[image]